# Django stubs interrupt Pycharm autocomplete

Tags: python, django, pycharm, django-stubs

I have a django app with several models. Here is autocomplete when I filter objects

[image]

Then I install django-stubs for MyPy

```
pip install django-stubs
```

Now my autocomplete looks like this

[image]
[image]

When I delete django-stubs autocomplete works well, like on the first picture

```
pip uninstall django-stubs
```

So, is there a way to use django-stubs with Pycharm Django autocomplete?

I use Pycharm Professional 2019.1 and Python3.7

Comment: At the moment they could not be used simultaneously

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no known workaround for this issue.

A [ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-37744) open since August 2019 tracks the issue at JetBrains and they confirmed it was on their end.

> This particular one is on our side, but I'm working on identifying all the integration issues with django-stubs and will definitely let you know if I find something

At the time of writing, there has been no reported progress.